# LoaderManager fires all Loaders same time

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, android-loader

Firstly let me describe my case: I'm receiving list of categories which populate `RecyclerView`. Each `View` on this list is some kind of widget and most common is another list (horizontal `RecyclerView`) with some news (also parsed from JSON).

I'm keeping all stuff in `ContentProvider` and `SQLiteDatabase` (with helper), which contains two tables - for categories and for news (each have category id key). So I'm using `Loader` for each widget to load data from database or if missing I'm downloading proper data and inserting into db. And then loader automatically refresh list delivering new cursor.

At once there may be present on the screen two (or more) horizontal lists with news. Each of these lists is registering own `Loader` like here:

```
loaderManager.initLoader(getWidgetCategory().getCategoryID(), null, getLoader());
```

under `getLoader();` we have same `Loader` (for widgets with news) like below:

```
private class NewsLoader implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(final int id, final Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(getContext(),
                CustomContract.News.CONTENT_URI,
                CustomContract.News.PROJECTION_ALL,
                CustomContract.News.KEY_CATEGORY_ID+"=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(getWidgetCategory().getCategoryID())},
                CustomContract.News.ORDER_BY_DEFAULT
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(final Loader<Cursor> loader, final Cursor data) {
        if (data.getCount()>=15) {
            swapCursor(data);
            displayContent();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(final Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

And the problem is: when I download and insert to database news from only one category all the `Loader`s are firing refreshing lists and it is really bad for performance... For example - there are two horizontal lists with news on the screen, we are scrolling a bit down and another (third) is coming. It doesn't have any news so background task is downloading them and inserting into db and then `LoaderManager` fires `Loader` for third widget. BUT not only... Also `Loaders` attached to two lists above are firing refreshing own lists.

I'm assuming there is a problem with same `CONTENT_URI`, maybe other params in `CursorLoader` constructor. The only change in there (for every news horizontal list widget) is `WHERE` clause with different category id and all `Loader`s are getting content from the same db table. How can I keep firing only one `Loader` for widget, which downloaded/inserted news? Note that id of registered loader and `WHERE` selection are the same...

Like I wrote there might be different types of widgets (and also lists, but not with news), which are populated from other tables and their `Loader`s are not firing with news `Loader`s. I'm assuming that if I get list of categories with only just-text-widgets (also shared db table) downloading text for one of the widgets will fire all `Loader's and redraw other widgets.

**edit:**

In other, short words: in my custom `ContentProvider` I have overriden `query` method, which contains line:

```
@Override
public Cursor query(
        final Uri uri,
        final String[] projection,
        final String selection,
        final String[] selectionArgs,
        String sortOrder
) {
    //selection, etc.
    //newly created cursor from selection above
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
}
```

and it's notifying all observing `Loader`s with passed `uri`. I have few lists (does not matter in fact that these are `RecyclerView`s) which are consuming data from one URI, but are passing custom selection param to each `CursorLoader`. But URI is common for all so all loaders are notified and I want to notify only this one, which fired database activity. I want to notify only one `Loader` with known id, which is also passed to `query` method inside `selectionArgs`. Yeah, I know that this might be impossible inside `query`, but maybe another way? For notifying `Loader`s not only by their URI

Comment: Please post the code that creates the `CursorAdapter`.  Are you using the flags parameter to register a `ContentObserver`?

Comment: Ignore previous comment, see my answer.

Comment: I think @alexlockwood should weigh in on this one.

Comment: @kris - since `RecyclerView` does not have `CursorAdapter` I'm using [smth like this](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> URI is common for all so all loaders are notified and I want to notify only this one, which fired database activity.

The easiest fix is to create a URI pattern where the URI is different for each category, so when you call `Cursor.setNoficationUri()` each cursor (and ultimately, each loader) will only receive ContentChanged notifications for the data it's concerned with.

There's no way to turn off the `ContentObserver` on a `CursorLoader`, so if you absolutely positively can't have different URIs, then the only other thing I can suggest is to write a `Loader<Cursor>` subclass that knows when to register and unregister its observer on the cursor.

(Edited from earlier answer)

Comment: bullet one: `initLoader` method get category ID for each `Loader`, so they are different and unique. bullet two: where to add this logic? when I'm receiving new cursor in `onLoadFinished` the old one is already closed, so i _have_ to replace this in my adapter, with old `Cursor` list will crash. Also provider is doing some work, so even if old `Cursor` remain opened (and I manage swapping by own) app is still doing unnecessary work with selecting data for all `Loader`s while I need for only one. see my edit with more precise (and short) description

Comment: this answer is sufficient for me, I'm going to redesign some project assumptions to fit `Loader`s behaviour... thank you